# Export Sql Server data to formatted Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, export

Is there a way to export some data from SQL Server to previously formatted Excel?
E.g. user has formatted Excel for his own report and want to have data from Sql (rows) in this report?
How this can be achieved? Thanks!

Comment: Link `SQL Server` to a separate sheet then use formula to pre-formatted sheet to get data SQL linked sheet.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. This could be fine solution for known number of rows. But, what if I don't know how many rows will be in report?

Comment: If you don't know then how you will pre-format the report. Then may be you have to format columns/rows after loading data.

Comment: I can format headers, font, color of headers, logo, put some formulas on columns, etc. But, thanks anyway for the first answer.

Comment: Run the query in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to move data between SQL Server and Excel.

```
' set a reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library'
Sub ADOExcelSQLServer()
     ' Carl SQL Server Connection
     '
     ' FOR THIS CODE TO WORK
     ' In VBE you need to go Tools References and check Microsoft Active X Data Objects 2.x library
     '
     
    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim Server_Name As String
    Dim Database_Name As String
    Dim User_ID As String
    Dim Password As String
    Dim SQLStr As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
     
    Server_Name = "your_server_name" ' Enter your server name here
    Database_Name = "NORTHWND" ' Enter your database name here
    User_ID = "" ' enter your user ID here
    Password = "" ' Enter your password here
    SQLStr = "SELECT * FROM [Customers]" ' Enter your SQL here
     
    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
    ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"
     
    rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic
     ' Dump to spreadsheet
    For iCols = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, iCols + 1).Value = rs.Fields(iCols).Name
    Next
    With Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a2:z500") ' Enter your sheet name and range here
        '.ClearContents
        .CopyFromRecordset rs
    End With
     '            Tidy up
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Cn.Close
    Set Cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to generate Excel by using Export Wizard..
An excellent article to get start.

https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/how-to-import-and-export-sql-server-data-to-an-excel-file/